# hokuyo_listener_cu_missing_library

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi to everybody

I am now trying the application using ROS (Robot Operative System).

I found  "hokuyo_listener_cu" node source code.

in the code there is a library called  "PointCloudWithOrigin.h"

"#include "hokuyo_listener_cu/PointCloudWithOrigin.h""

I can not find the library anywhere, I supposed that it could be here,

http://code.google.com/p/prairiedog/source/browse/trunk/hokuyo_listener_cu/?r=65#hokuyo_listener_cu%2Fsrc

but it is not.

I am just wondering where can I find it.

And thank you very much for your help :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12605/hokuyo_listener_cu_missing_library/) by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 556 on 2012-01-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The PointCloudWithOrigin.h is automatically generated from PointCloudWithOrigin.msg using the `rosmake [node_to_make' command (this is how ROS does all message data structures, see http://www.ros.org/wiki/Messages

---

Originally posted by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) with karma: 556 on 2012-01-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0